# Where can I find the "Destructive Smite" paladin spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, paladin

In the list of spells in the *Player's Handbook*, one of the level 5 paladin spells is "Destructive Smite". However, I can't find the spell description.

Where can I find the description of the "Destructive Smite" spell?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Destructive Smite* is most likely renamed to ***Destructive Wave***, as it is also a 5th level spell, and has the same spell description as the spell *Destructive Smite* which was in the Alpha playtest.

Comment: FYI, it looks like this was officially answered via [errata](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/Errata_PH.pdf). You may want to adjust your answer from speculation to proof :)

Answer (score 12):

## It should be listed as *destructive wave*, as corrected in errata.

The [very first PHB errata in 2015](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/Errata_PH.pdf) corrected the spell name in the paladin spell listing from *destructive smite* to *destructive wave*. The description of [*destructive wave*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/destructive-wave) appears on p. 231 of the PHB.

[D&D 5e co-creator Mike Mearls had earlier confirmed that this was an error in a September 2014 tweet](https://twitter.com/mikemearls/status/511917261020360706):

> Destructive smite spell in paladin listing should refer to destructive wave in spell descriptions

Answer (score 1):

Destructive Smite has been renamed into Destructive Wave, as far as I can tell.

[This post by Brian Michaluk on the ENWorld forums](https://www.enworld.org/threads/finally.357793/page-19#post-6352874) should have the answer you are looking for. I cannot speak for reliability. The post states:

> > Is Damning Smite in? And what is it like now?
>
> I dont see anything by that name but there are some smites as class features and some as spells.
>
> uhh ohhhh I think I just found a typo in the book
>
> lvl 5 paladin spell list "destructive smite" but in the spells list descriptions I only find "Destructive wave" which I think is what its supposed to be

Comment: Could you include some quotes from the link for posterity in case it goes down?

Comment: Could you explain what relevance that quote has to your answer? It is not obvious what this cut-and-paste of an effect description is supposed to demonstrate to a reader here.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I was asked to copy the post that I referenced into my answer. Though I've probably copied the wrong information on reflection.

Comment: I've edited the answer to point to the post in that thread that actually mentions that *destructive smite* (which appeared in the paladin spell list in the first printing) should have referred to *destructive wave* instead. That said, as noted in my answer, the [very first PHB errata in 2015](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/Errata_PH.pdf) acknowledged and corrected this error.