# Are there any spells that aren't on any class's spell list?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Chapter 11 of the 5e Player's Handbook has a list of spells each spellcasting class can learn, followed by a description of all the spells in the game.

I am wondering: are there any spells that are described in the second part of the chapter that aren't in any class spell list in the first part of the chapter?

I am thinking those could be spells only learned by certain class or race features, or spells added to the spell list by sub classes. They could also just be spells described but not mentioned anywhere else in the book, for whatever reason.

My questions regards the PHB primarily. But I would also by interested in knowing if this is the case for any of the supplementary books, that add new spells, like XGtE.

Comment: Just to let you know, yes, *XGtE* does have them broken out by class spell list.  Are you asking as a player or as a DM?  Also, do you have the Monster Manual (or access to it) and the DMG(or access to it?)

Comment: I am a DM, and I do have both the MM and the DMG.

Comment: What difference does asking as a player or DM make in this case?

Comment: Because the only resource a player is assumed to have is  PHB, and the DM and MM are (to be technical) "DM" tools.  If you were asking as a player, the PHB would be the only resource one needed to refer to. All I was able to come up with were some spell like abilities, so I think Joshjurg's got you covered. And I guess you know that you can make your own spells, per the DMG, but that wasn't your question.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

## There is the Ravnica spell *encode thoughts*

While not the PHB, the *Guildmasters' Guide to Ravnica* includes character options for use in that particular setting (Ravnica). Among these the *encode thoughts* cantrip which is only obtainable through the Dimir Guild Background option (pages 45-50). That feature adds it to the class list for you, much in the same way the Fiend Patron adds *fireball* to the list of that particular Warlock, even though it is not on that class list in general.

[D&D Beyond incorrectly lists it](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/encode-thoughts) as a Wizard spell, which is probably because Wizard is the only spellcaster class suggested for a Dimir character.

## Dunamancy spells from Explorer's Guide to Wildemount

The [dunamancy spells](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/egtw/character-options-subclasses#DunamancySpellList) don't start on any classes spell list, but become availible to one or both of the wizard subclasses also in that book or by DM opt-in to other spellcasters. (Thanks to @raithyn for pointing these out.)

Comment: D&D Beyond's database probably requires it to be listed *somewhere*, too. "No Class" may not be an option.

Comment: I was going to say that technically, Dimir Guild background isn't the _only_ way. There's also Pact of the Tome but then the wording says "from any class’s spell list" so that's not a thing

Comment: Wouldn't a Bard also be able to get that spell through Magical Secrets?

Comment: @WakiNadiVellir No, Bards also "choose [] spells from any class", and *encode thoughts* is not from any class.

Answer (score 8):

### No. There are no *secret spells*.   But:

***Trap the Soul*** does not exist in 5e but appears in the Wizard's spell list in the original printing of the PHB. [Details here.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46098/where-can-i-find-the-trap-the-soul-8th-level-wizard-spell)

***Destructive Wave*** is in the Paladin's spell list, but it's listed as *Destructive Smite* in the original printing of the PHB. There is no entry for *Destructive Smite* under the spell descriptions.

It's listed correctly in the D&D Beyond Compendium and in the official Errata. [Details here.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46095/where-can-i-find-the-destructive-smite-paladin-spell)

From the [PHB errata](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf#page=3):

> ***Paladin Spells (p. 209).*** Under 5th Level, “*destructive smite*” has been changed to “*destructive wave*.”
>
> ***Wizard Spells (p. 211).*** Under 8th Level, “*Trap the Soul*” has been removed.

Answer (score -3):

There used to be the spell *Wall of Water* that was exclusive to the Triton race from VGtM, but when XGtE came out it was added to the Druid, Sorcerer, and Wizard spell lists.

Comment: *Wall of Water* was released as a spell much earlier in the Elemental Evil Player's companion and was available to those classes.