# How do I search DnD Beyond for spells that force movement

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-beyond

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to search the [DnD Beyond spell interface](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells) that force movement (e.g pushing and pulling)

There doesn't seem to be a way to search for that though, or anything else in the spell text.

How can I search for these kinds of spells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of approaches available, neither is perfect, but should help find them:

## The spell tag: Control

D&D Beyond adds some metadata to the spells it lists, including spell tags. Forced movement falls under [Control](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells?filter-tags=6), but does a couple of other things (such as preventing movement, etc.). Do note that D&D Beyond's tagging isn't perfect; eg. [*gravity fissure*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/gravity-fissure) doesn't have the Control tag, and [*encode thoughts* is tagged as a Wizard spell](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/158102/52137). You can use this in combination with the other features of the spell listing, such as classes, schools, and levels.

## D&D Beyond's general search

For searching through the spell description text, you can use D&D Beyond's general search (found in the top bar) and filter only to spells (click on the big spells icon). Example for "pulled" [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/search?q=pulled&f=spells&c=spells). The search is fairly simple, but works well for keywords which aren't too common. You'd need a separate search for each keyword, and this method won't catch spells which has this effect without using a wording you expected. Note that it's limited to 35 results, so if more than 35 spells contain the word you searched for, you won't find all of them.